# How to prevent Java Generics forcing duplicate code?

Tags: java, variables, generics, duplicates

I'm trying to write an `AnimalGroup` factory class that returns an instance which contains various different types of `Animal`. Unfortunately i'm being forced to duplicate code due to what seems like Java generics limitations. I've tried every possible combination of wildcards etc that I can think of with no luck.

Here's the code:

```
public AnimalGroup<?> getAnimalGroup (String animalName) {
    if(animalName.equals("Yetti")) {
        AnimalGroup<Yetti> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<>(Yetti.class);
        animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
        return animalGroup;
    }
    else {
        AnimalGroup<Doge> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<>(Doge.class);
        animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
        return animalGroup;
    }
}
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
public AnimalGroup<?> getAnimalGroup (String animalName) {
    Class<?> animalClass = Doge.class;

    if(animalName.equals("Yetti")) {
        animalClass = Yetti.class;
    }

    AnimalGroup<animalClass> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<>(animalClass);
    animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
    return animalGroup;
}
```

**Update:**

Using the `<? extends Animal>` solution, the following additional processing code no longer works:

```
// Pseudo-ish code
public <T extends Animal> void setAnimals (T animals) { this.animals = animals; }

List<? extends Animal> animals = getAnimals(animalClass);
animalGroup.setAnimals(animals);
```

The error given is pretty confusing:

```
setAnimals(java.util.List<capture<? extends Animal>>) in AnimalGroup cannot be applied to (java.util.List<capture<? extends Animal>>)
```

Any help much obliged. Thanks!
Ben.

Comment: The part between `<>` has to be a type name, it can't be a variable or an expression that resolves to a reference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yea, sucks!

Comment: Are all the Animal classes (Yetti, Doge, etc) in the same package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are Doge and Yeti extending the same Animal class? If yes then you could do

```
 public AnimalGroup<? extends Animal> getAnimalGroup (String animalName) {
    Class<? extends Animal> animalClass = Doge.class;

    if("Yetti".equals(animalName)) {
        animalClass = Yetti.class;
    }

    AnimalGroup<? extends Animal> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<>(animalClass);
    animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
    return animalGroup;
    }
```

If they not, then well, they should :)

I cannot really understand the edit I did a POC and the following code works (assuming interface A and implementing classes B and C:

```
private static List<? extends A> generateObjects(boolean isItB) {
        if (isItB) {
            return new ArrayList<B>() {
                {
                    add(new B());
                }
            };
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<C>() {
                {
                    add(new C());
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private static void consumeObjects(List<? extends A> consuming) {
        for (A a : consuming) {
            a.doStuff();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends A> generatedBs = generateObjects(false);
        consumeObjects(generatedBs);


    }
```

Comment: Yes they do, this does work and I had been using the same solution before, however it then poses a further problem - i've updated the question to demonstrate this!

Comment: Would you mind showing the actual code? Because what you wrote in the edit should be working (just did a quick poc to check it and it was), although your pseudo code is a bit mix of wildcards and generic arguments but I just assumed a typo, maybe I was wrong

Comment: Can't show the actual code for security reasons, but I managed to get it working by dropping the type params on the List, i.e. `List<? extends Animal> animals` -> `List animals` and it works fine... Java generics are so broken.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `enum`:

```
class AnimalGroup<T> {

    AnimalGroup(Class<T> itsClass) {

    }

    public void doSomeProcessing() {

    }
}

class Yetti {

}

class Dog {

}

// Connects the name of the animal with the 
enum Animal {

    Dog(Dog.class),
    Yetti(Yetti.class),
    // Can also have aliases this way.
    AbominableSnowman(Yetti.class);
    final Class itsClass;

    Animal(Class c) {
        itsClass = c;
    }
}

public AnimalGroup<?> getAnimalGroup(String animalName) {
    Animal animal = Animal.valueOf(animalName);
    AnimalGroup<?> g = new AnimalGroup<>(animal.itsClass);
    g.doSomeProcessing();
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it without String classnames with pure generic using parameterized generic methods like this:

```
class Wrapper {

   public <T> AnimalGroup<T> getAnimalGroup (Class<T> cl) {   

       AnimalGroup<T> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<T>(cl);
       animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
       return animalGroup;               
   }
}
```

Then you AnimalGroup and Animal classes might look like this:

```
   class AnimalGroup<T> {
       private Class<T> cl;

       public AnimalGroup(Class<T> cl) {
           this.cl = cl;
       }

       public void doSomeProcessing() {
           System.out.println(cl);
        /*
        here i just printout the classname, but you can do proccessing like this
        if (cl.equals(Yetti.class)) do one thing, else do another, etc.            
        */
       }
    }

    class Yetti{}

    class Dog{}
```

And a simple test:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Wrapper an = new Wrapper();
        an.getAnimalGroup(Yetti.class);
        //new AnimalGroup<String>(String.class).doSomeProcessing();

     }
}
```

which returns following output

```
class Yetti
```

As you see, your animals are distinquished based on their types stored in Class cl variable of AnimalGroup class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a lookup `Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>>`:

```
private static Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>> map = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Animal>>() {
    {
        put("Yetti", Yetti.class);
        put("Doge", Doge.class);
    }
};

public static AnimalGroup<? extends Animal> getAnimalGroup(String animalName) {
    AnimalGroup<? extends Animal> animalGroup = new AnimalGroup<>(map.get(animalName));
    animalGroup.doSomeProcessing();
    return animalGroup;
}
```